# Ruby: no such file to load -- EC2

Tags: ruby, rubygems, amazon-ec2

I am using the script from this website: http://dysinger.net/2008/10/13/using-amazon-ec2-metadata-as-a-simple-dns/
I have to say i am a PHPPerson and i know pretty much nothing about ruby. Anyway i am using this scipt on an ec2 instance with Amazon Linux, so I installed ruby and rubygems with yum, and I did

```
gem install amazon-ec2
```

$ gem list:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

amazon-ec2 (0.9.17)
rubygems-update (1.8.25)
xml-simple (1.1.2)
```

looks good, but when i run the script i get:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require':   no such file to load -- EC2 (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /usr/local/sbin/hosts:2
from /usr/local/sbin/hosts:2:in `each'
from /usr/local/sbin/hosts:2
```

...why?
I tried to figure this for one hour but still have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blog post is a little bit outdated. In order to use the amazon-ec2 gem, you need to `require 'AWS'`, not `require 'EC2'`. This means you have to change the second line to:

```
%w(optparse rubygems AWS resolv pp).each {|l| require l}
```

You will also have to change this line:

```
EC2::Base.new(options).describe_instances # etc...
```

to

```
AWS::EC2::Base.new(options).describe_instances # etc...
```